# Encrypting a string with PublicKey + Base64 encryption

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, public-key

I have a RSA public key in String format and I want to encrypt a string using the same to Base 64. Here is the code that I am using for this:

```
function encrypt(String pin){ 
  String key = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiOnM5t6w2ZD6dpA4/MzSTAOt0IYpnsmGSAIfIVgGntI+fI4wbvUvMIhaLN3fHrjyuNGFdYw+yuoXYkapajt6VTZJniaatSiq6bwQ7R0UAop6haFSAwjnmReqexJvcKyqUsTfcfFypPpsYRewh/48/jmc/6ND+ugxDd52prkPUrbj+nnO0z3DBoUCpgDMRvW2hWXv6kZ654gp+wIAQnxbdwRMy6FZbrHjkA3tc6U0CHK+KjxAfzWAK+yI+ofskM4qk50J7y9hUZ7lLikqWZWKiqh8xiDk1kgu+FIjVh+fylKpa3gWmPPn0fSpBJjuenc1OQVmZ718a3388DjzFlYOLwIDAQAB";
  byte[] sigBytes2 = Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
  Log.d("WS", "new key is: " + key);
  try {
    PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(sigBytes2));
    encryptedBase64PIN = encode(publicKey, pin);
    Log.d("WSA", "encoded key is: " + encryptedBase64PIN);
    // getSecToken();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public static String encode(Key publicKey, String data)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
    InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

  byte[] byteData = data.getBytes(); // convert string to byte array

  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");       
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);      
  byte[] encryptedByteData = cipher.doFinal(byteData);

  String s = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedByteData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
  return s; // convert encrypted byte array to string and return it
}
```

When I send the same output to the server, it says "cannot decrypt the PIN". Why is this?

Comment: Your top method is not valid Java. Did you mean `public void` where you've typed `function`?

Comment: yes it was cut - copy mistake :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I send the same output to the server, it says "cannot decrypt the PIN". Why is this?

There could be *many* reasons for this. If you have the code for the server decryption, please add it to your question.

Reasons may include:

- Wrong encryption mode. You've selected `RSA/ECB/NoPadding` but perhaps the server is expecting something else?
- Base64 encoding - is the server definitely expecting this?
- The message is "cannot decrypt PIN". If the `data` you are encrypting is the PIN are you sure you should be encrypting ASCII bytes?

Comment: Also bear in mind that there are multiple attacks against raw RSA encryption with PKCS1Padding, so reconsider using this.